# Create reactive form Array with different Validations in array

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I recently started on Angular4 reactive Forms, i want to create a form array based on below Structure

```
"ContactPoints":
[{"ContactPointID":33,"EntityID":9,"System":"phone","Value":"1234567890","Use":"work","Rank":1,"InUseStart":"2017-07-14T00:00:00","InUseEnd":"2017-10-22T00:00:00"},
{"ContactPointID":34,"EntityID":9,"System":"phone","Value":"1234567890","Use":"home","Rank":1,"InUseStart":"2017-07-14T00:00:00","InUseEnd":"2017-10-22T00:00:00"},
{"ContactPointID":35,"EntityID":9,"System":"fax","Value":"1234567890","Use":"work","Rank":1,"InUseStart":"2017-07-14T00:00:00","InUseEnd":"2017-10-22T00:00:00"},
{"ContactPointID":36,"EntityID":9,"System":"email","Value":"kishore@abc.com","Use":"work","Rank":1,"InUseStart":"2017-07-21T00:00:00","InUseEnd":"2017-10-29T00:00:00"},
{"ContactPointID":37,"EntityID":9,"System":"email","Value":"kishore@abc.com","Use":"home","Rank":1,"InUseStart":"2017-07-21T00:00:00","InUseEnd":"2017-10-29T00:00:00"}],
```

Below is HTML Syntax, where i need to get respective input values in value and system and use will be hard-coded values and validations based on system, any suggestions in achieving this will be very helpful

```
 <div class="col-md-4" formArrayName="ContactPoints">
                <div class="form-group form-group-default  " formGroupName=0>
                    <label class="control-label">Main Number</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="Value">
                </div>
            </div>

<div class="col-md-4" formArrayName="ContactPoints">
                    <div class="form-group form-group-default  " formGroupName=1>
                        <label class="control-label">Main Number</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="Value">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: so where is you validation rules?

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com i want the validations also to be achieved based on system value in JSON, suppose if "System":"phone" it should trigger phone number Validation, and i am confused where to put Validation rules in above scenario

Comment: How do you declare your `FormGroup` instance?

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic forms, https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form, to achieve this. Making each input type(in your case system:- phone, email, fax) as separate components and adding the validations in the components will help you achieve your scenario. 
Refer : https://toddmotto.com/angular-dynamic-components-forms gives a good example of how to achieve this kind of dynamic forms